# How to loop through a table to see if the checkbox are checked

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I'm trying to loop through a table to see if a check box is checked. On button click SendCheckEmail is called. I'm getting an error EmailForm is not declared and also I'm unsure of how to loop through the table to process each checkbox that is checked.

```
 Sub Page_Load
    If Request.QueryString("show") <> "" then
      dim Sr as StreamReader = New StreamReader("d:\netdrvs\prs\emaillist\" &   Request.QueryString("show"),FileMode.Open)
      output="<table id=EmailForm border=1 padding=4  >" & VBCR
      output+="<tr><td>Customer Code</td><td>Email</td><td>Invoice Number</td><td>Regarding</td><td>  <input type=checkbox name=chkHeader id=chkHeader></td></tr>"
      While Not SR.EndOfStream
      dim Temp(3) as String
      Temp = Split(SR.ReadLine(),vbTab)
      dim temp2(3) as String
      Temp2 = Split(Temp(0),"_")
      output += "<tr>" & VBCR
      output += "<td>" & Temp2(1) & "</td>" & VBCR
      output += "<td>" & Temp(1) & "</td>" & VBCR
      output += "<td>" & Temp2(0) & "</td>" & VBCR
      output += "<td>" & Temp(2) & "</td>" & VBCR
      output += "<td> <input type=checkbox name=chkRow id=chkRow> </td>" & VBCR
      output += "</tr>"& VBCR   
    End While
    output+="</table>" & VBCR   
    SR.Close()
    ProcessChk.Visible = True
   end if
End Sub

Sub SendCheckEmail (sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) 

    Dim item 

    For each item in EmailForm 
        'loop through each row
    NEXT

End Sub

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Lathams Invoice Email Sending</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("[id*=chkHeader]").live("click", function () {
    var chkHeader = $(this);
    var grid = $(this).closest("table");
    $("input[type=checkbox]", grid).each(function () {
        if (chkHeader.is(":checked")) {
            $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
            $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("selected");
        } else {
            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
            $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
$("[id*=chkRow]").live("click", function () {
    var grid = $(this).closest("table");
    var chkHeader = $("[id*=chkHeader]", grid);
    if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("selected");
        chkHeader.removeAttr("checked");
    } else {
        $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("selected");
        if ($("[id*=chkRow]", grid).length == $("[id*=chkRow]:checked", grid).length) {
            chkHeader.attr("checked", "checked");
        }
    }
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:label id="test" runat="server" />

  <%=output%>



   <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <asp:Button id="ProcessFile" visible="false" runat="server" Text="Process Emails" onClick="SendMails" />
    <asp:Button id="ProcessChk" visible="false" runat="server" Text="Process Checked Emails" OnClick="SendCheckEmail" />

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show your .aspx page

Comment: Okay! I have re-edit my question

Comment: EmailForm is which control?? Are you using Any `Repeater`,`GridView`

Comment: its just a table, tried using a GridView but when I tried to grab the information from the text file it didn't like it. So I went for a table

Comment: posted answer try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `runat="server"` to `EmailForm`

and then

**IN C#**

```
foreach (var item in tbl.Rows)
        {
            HtmlTableRow row = (HtmlTableRow)item;

            foreach (var item1 in row.Controls)
            {
                HtmlTableCell cell = (HtmlTableCell)item1;



            }
        }
```

**In VB.NET**

```
Dim rowitem
Dim cellitem 

For Each rowitem In tbl.Rows
HtmlTableRow row = (HtmlTableRow)rowitem;


For Each cellitem In tbl.Rows
HtmlTableCell cell = (HtmlTableCell)cellitem;
// cell items

next

next


// can directly access checkbox if it is set to runat='server'
```

Answer (score 1):

EmailForm is not a a server control, so you cannot access it in CodeBehind.

You could try using a repeater or a table control that you bind to the file contents.

Otherwise you could add the email address as value attribute in the input tag. 
      output += "  " & VBCR

Then you will receive a comma separated list of email addresses by accessing Request("chkRow")

Comment: only if you define the runat=server in the aspx file. not if you add it through the output variable. I think you should go this route: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/12/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo_21.html